# State of components from a list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I got a list with 2 react components and their initial color is black.

The objective is next , when I click on a component I want to set the state of the previous on black if it is orange.
I tried with useState hook but I didn't have much success.
If someone could give me some hints it will be perfect.

```
const Square = () => {

const [actualColor, setColor] = useState("black") 
const onClickEnterHandler = () => setColor("orange")

return(
    <div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Square
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant component's source code?

Comment: "_I didn't have much success_" Why not? What happens with this code? Why is that wrong? :-)

Comment: because when i click on the second square it doesn't change the color of the first one from orange to black and vice verse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I got it correctly, when clicking on square 2, you want square 1 to be black and square 2 (currently active square) to be orange.

If so, then try:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  // Callback function to be passed down to Square component
  const onSquareClick = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  };

  const myTwoSquares = [0, 1].map((i) => (
    <Square
      index={i}
      active={i === activeIndex} // This is important
      onClick={onSquareClick}
      key={i}
    />
  ));

  return <div>{myTwoSquares}</div>;
```

Then in your Square component, you can conditionally check the `active` prop and set the active Square to orange.

```
const Square = ({ index, active, onClick }) => {
  const actualColor = active ? "orange" : "black";
  const onSquareClick = () => {
    onClick(index);
  };
return (
    <div
     onClick={onSquareClick}
     style={{ backgroundColor: actualColor}}
    ></div>  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change multiple components, you have to move your state to their common parent and pass the state as prop or use React Context.

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [color, setColor] = useState('black')
   const changeColor = () => setColor("orange")
   return (
     <>
       <Square color={color} changeColor={changeColor} />
       <Square color={color} changeColor={changeColor} />
     </>
)}


const Square = ({color, changeColor}) => {

  return(
    <div onClick={changeColor} style={{color: color}}>
      content
    </div>
  )
}
```